# Set opacity for TextView

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a TextView, and I wonder if there is a way to set alpha (opacity) for both text and image in a TextView programmatically. I found 'alpha' property in TextView properties, it affects to text of the TextView but will it affect to image in the TextView too? How do I do it programmatically?

Comment: Why don't you try before ask?

Comment: Did you tried to use setApha? It must do, what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
your_variable_name.setALpha(0f);
```

f = float

0f means 0%

1f means 100%

0.8f means 80%

You can use setAlpha() in ImageViews also.

If you want to smooth the process(use an animation) :

```
your_variable_name.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(300);
```

300 is millis that means 1000 = 1 sec

Comment: glad that helped you, but i believe you could  have searched a little more before asking a question, most of your questions  or a big capacity of them (in the future) are already answered in other topics

Comment: warning setAlpha take an int from 0 to 255

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your views in a ViewGroup (`FrameLayout,RelativeLayout ...`) and call `viewGroup.setAlpha(yourValue)`

Comment: without wrapping can I set it directly ?